# C#- Filter data based on child class or using string query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, filter

Hi I have a scenario to filter the data based sub-object field please help me. From controller as query I pass Expression String.

```
class MasterDocument
{
    private Id;    
    public ICollection<SubDocument> documents { get; set; }     
}  

class SubDocument 
{
    private Id;
    public int Age { get; set; } 
}  

var filterQuery = "documents.Age == 25"; 
var filteredResult = MasterDocument.Where(filterQuery).ToList();
```

to filter the Data 
how to create Expression from string to filter data from Substructure.

Comment: Please format your code properly. I was going to wrap it in tags but it's not indented properly in the first place. You should copy and paste code directly from the code editor if you can. If you can't, take the time to indent it yourself.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're using a string to filter like that in the first place?

Comment: It seems you may look for a library like [Dynamic LINQ](https://dynamic-linq.net/) to process your *string-like filter*. PS: This is not a promotion post, Dynamic LINQ doesn't pay me for the advertising =P.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's quite complicated topic, but i will first give code example and later focus on caveats:

I would follow approach and define it as another extension method:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApp2;

public static class WhereExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection,
        string filterExpression)
    {
        // Most probably you'd like to have here more sophisticated validations.
        var itemsToCompare = filterExpression.Split("==")
            .Select(x => x.Trim())
            .ToArray();

        if (itemsToCompare.Length != 2)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var property = itemsToCompare[0];
        var valueToCompareAgainst = itemsToCompare[1];

        var memberExpr = source.GetMemberExpression(property);

        var comparisonExpr = Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Call(memberExpr, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString")),
            Expression.Constant(valueToCompareAgainst)
        );

        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(comparisonExpr, source);

        return collection.Where(predicate.Compile());
    }

    public static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression(
        this ParameterExpression parameter,
        string memberExpression)
    {
        var properties = memberExpression.Split('.');

        if (!properties.Any())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        var memberExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, properties[0]);

        foreach (var property in properties.Skip(1))
        {
            memberExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(memberExpr, property);
        }

        return memberExpr;
    }
}
```

and the usage would be:

```
using ConsoleApp2;

var example = new[]
{
    new TestClass() { Id = 1, Description = "a" },
    new TestClass() { Id = 2, Description = "a" },
    new TestClass() { Id = 3, Description = "b" },
    new TestClass() { Id = 4, Description = "b" },
};

var result1 = example.Where("Id == 1").ToList();
var result2 = example.Where("Description == b").ToList();

Console.WriteLine("Items with Id == 1");
result1.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Id: {x.Id} , Descr: {x.Description}"));

Console.WriteLine("Items with Description == b");
result2.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Id: {x.Id} , Descr: {x.Description}"));


class TestClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This codes returns:
[image]

NOW, THE CAVEATS

It's very tricky to cast value to compare against to an arbitrary type `T`, that's why i reversed the problem, and I call "ToString" on whetever member we want to compare

```
Expression.Call(memberExpr, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"))
```

But this also could have it's own issues, as often "ToString" returns default tpye name. But works well with integers and simple value types.